# get raw text from textarea

Tags: javascript, html, unicode

I want to get the raw text from a texarea, with this I mean without converting unicode values, for example:

```js
let textArea=document.querySelector("textarea");
let value=textArea.value;
let valueSpan=document.querySelector(".value .text")
let valueinnerHTML=document.querySelector(".innerHTML .text");
console.log(value);
console.log(textArea.innerHTML);
valueSpan.textContent =value;
valueinnerHTML.textContent=textArea.innerHTML;
```

```css
.wrapper{

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}
.test{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 3px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="hide">
Unicode: &#128036;
Icon:    
</textarea>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="value test">
   <h3> Value</h3>
    <span class="text"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="innerHTML test">
   <h3> InnerHTML</h3>
    <span class="text"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to be get the raw text so when I get text area value, I get "&#128036" instead of

Comment: Did you try `innerHTML` instead of `value`?

Comment: If you want to get the value of the `<textarea>` after a person has typed characters into it, your only choice is to get the value as a string. The `innerHTML` approach only works for the content present at page load time.

Comment: @Taplar it does not work, see the updated question

Comment: @Pointy I just want to get the value after the page load, not when the person is typing

Comment: Well in Firefox `innerHTML` gives you the content, and so does `.textContent`, but the HTML entity has already been parsed to build the browser's internal representation of the text in the text node(s).  Some browsers might decide to give back an entity or entities for some code points, I guess.

Comment: @Pointy is correct. The browser has already parsed the HTML and turned it into DOM elements, and the original representation is not available to you. This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). *Why* do you need "the raw text"? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Pointy any cross browser approach? at least in chrome and firefox

Comment: @JordanRunning I'm creating a text editor that uses simbols to represent a latex content,  and , and I want to diferenciate a &#128036 and  so I know if the user wants to represent a latex content or wants to show the symbol

Answer (score 2):

Using "".`codePointAt(0)` will return you "128036". Check out [this](https://thekevinscott.com/emojis-in-javascript/) if you want to read about it.

```js
let value=document.querySelector("textarea").value
let span=document.querySelector("span");
span.textContent =value.codePointAt(0);
```

```html
 <textarea class="hide">


</textarea>
<span></span>
```

Comment: I'ts not what I want, I want to get the whole raw text value without converting unicode

Answer (score 1):

Use Unicode to present "&" in order to display the uni-code

& # 1 2 8 0 3 6; to display & # 1 2 8 0 3 6;

```js
let textArea=document.querySelector("textarea");
let value=textArea.value;
let valueSpan=document.querySelector(".value .text")
let valueinnerHTML=document.querySelector(".innerHTML .text");
console.log(value);
console.log(textArea.innerHTML);
valueSpan.textContent =value;
valueinnerHTML.textContent=textArea.innerHTML;
```

```css
.wrapper{

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}
.test{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 3px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="hide">
Unicode: &#38;#128036;
Icon:    
</textarea>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="value test">
   <h3> Value</h3>
    <span class="text"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="innerHTML test">
   <h3> InnerHTML</h3>
    <span class="text"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

&#128036

Use Unicode to present &.